# Difference between NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount and NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

If my app want to support sharing from Safari browser, I will include the following 2 activation rules

[NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsextension/nsextensionattributes/nsextensionactivationrule/nsextensionactivationsupportswebpagewithmaxcount)

[NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsextension/nsextensionattributes/nsextensionactivationrule/nsextensionactivationsupportsweburlwithmaxcount)

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

However, does anyone has any idea, what is the differences among the 2 rules?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this answer has no official documentation and it is based on my experiments and development experience:

### NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount

This extension is focused on Links / URLs like sharing the URL from the browser, adding a reading list, there are plenty of tools like Pocket, Browsers, Raindrop that uses this one.

### NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount

This is specifically for WebPage itself and has nothing to do with sharing the URL, you can share the whole web page content like an overlay in a web page, let's say AdBlocker. Or perhaps you have seem before like "Print" or "Translate Page".